# What is the most efficient/fastest way to draw rectangles on the screen in WPF / MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

The following code draws rectangles in 2D grid. Everything is working fine except it is really slow when it has to draw more than 50,000 squares. I know it sounds like a lot of squares but I have the same program written in `C++/Qt` and it's a lot faster, it draws the 50,000 almost instantaneously wheres in C#/WPF it takes 50 seconds.

Is there a better/faster way to draw rectangles on the screen in WPF?

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="DrawingRectanglesWithMvvmLight.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        Height="319"
        Width="453.333"
        Title="MVVM Light Application"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0,0,2,0" Height="194" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF3E7AAC">

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PartsGrid}" Height="200" Margin="5,0,10,-6">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Background="#FFF1F0F0" Margin="10" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle 
                        Width="{Binding Width}" 
                       Height="{Binding Height}" 
                       Margin="{Binding Margin}"
                       Fill="{Binding Fill}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <Grid Margin="5,236,6,-69">
            <Button Content="Draw" Command="{Binding DrawCommand}" Margin="328,0,10,0" />
            <Button Content="Reset" Command="{Binding ResetCommand}" Margin="263,0,109,0" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Width}" RenderTransformOrigin="1.049,2.023" Margin="124,0,200,0"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Height}" Margin="0,0,334,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Class:**

```
namespace MvvmLightTEST.Model
{
    public class FSRectangle
    {
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public Thickness Margin { get; set; }
        public Brush Fill { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
namespace DrawingRectanglesWithMvvmLight.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<FSRectangle> PartsGrid { get; } = new ObservableCollection<FSRectangle>();

        public RelayCommand DrawCommand { get; }
        public RelayCommand ResetCommand { get; }

        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
        {
            DrawCommand = new RelayCommand(Draw);
            ResetCommand = new RelayCommand(Clear);
        }

        private void Draw()
        {
            Clear();

            int xParts = 250;
            int yParts = 200;
            for (int i = 0; i < xParts; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < yParts; j++) {
                    FSRectangle part = new FSRectangle();
                    part.Width = Width;
                    part.Height = Height;
                    part.Margin = new Thickness((part.Width + 1) * i, (part.Height + 1) * j, 0, 0);
                    part.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(170, 51, 51, 255));
                    PartsGrid.Add(part);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Clear()
        {
            PartsGrid.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

**UI**

[image]

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By not using MVVM due to the slow performance for this use case. Rectangles are `FrameworkElement`s which contain layout, a feature that does not scale  This is discussed many times in SO.

You might want to consider

- using `DrawingVisual` and `ContainerVisual` for lower level rendering with no layout overhead
- no MVVM
- create render visuals ahead of time rather than per render

[image]

Image [courtesy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview) Microsoft, used without permission.

MSDN has this to say on `DrawingVisual`

> The DrawingVisual is a lightweight drawing class that is used to render shapes, images, or text. This class is considered lightweight because it **does not provide layout or event handling, which improves its runtime performance**. For this reason, drawings are ideal for backgrounds and clip art. The DrawingVisual can be used to create a custom visual object.

### See also

- [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview)

Comment: I tried drawing the `Rectangle()`s directly in the code-behind and just by removing MVVM the performance improved a lot.  I guess I will have to draw the rectangles without using MVVM. I will also look into 'DrawingVisual' and 'ContainerVisual'. Can you elaborate a little bit more on your third suggestion? `create render visuals ahead of time rather than per render` Thanks.

Comment: If the things you want to draw are _static_ (or even if you intend to move them about but the count remains the same), then allocate them when the window is created and store them in a field, rather than during rendering.  This will make it more performant

Comment: Size and qty will be dynamic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Path with RectangleGeometry is an option:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-define-a-rectangle-using-a-rectanglegeometry

Comment: I don't think I can bind to `Rect()` so I would need to not use MVVM. I will give it a try without using MVVM and I will see how efficient it is. Thanks.